# Importing Python library smtplib

Tags: python, import, sikuli

I want to import the smtplib to the sikuli script I'm writing so Sikuli can send email automatically when the test is finished.

However, I encounter a problem that Sikuli cannot find the smtplib module in Python which I am sure it is installed and located in the Python27/Lib directory. Below is the code I am using. I use SikuliX 1.1.0 and Python 2.7.

---

```
import smtplib
sender = '<email address hidden>'
receivers = ['<email address hidden>']

message = """From: From Person <email address hidden>
To: To Person <email address hidden>
Subject: SMTP e-mail test

This is a test e-mail message.
"""

try:
   smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('test.com.hk')
   smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers, message)
   print "Successfully sent email"
except:
   print "Error: unable to send email"
```

---

When I run it in Sikuli IDE, it gives me:

"[error] script [ send ] stopped with error in line 2
[error] ImportError ( No module named utils )
[error] --- Traceback --- error source first line: module ( function ) statement 46: smtplib (  ) import email.utils
[error] --- Traceback --- end --------------"

Can anyone help? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have a file called `email.py` somewhere in your `sys.path`, which is shadowing the standard library's `email` package - it might even be the script you're testing.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.html

To fix, use anything else as the module/file name.

```
akg@limbo:~/scratch.d/20151012-stack33095084$ cat email.py 
import smtplib
sender = '<email address hidden>'
receivers = ['<email address hidden>']

message = """From: From Person <email address hidden>
To: To Person <email address hidden>
Subject: SMTP e-mail test

This is a test e-mail message.
"""

try:
   smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('test.com.hk')
   smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers, message)
   print "Successfully sent email"
except:
   print "Error: unable to send email"

akg@limbo:~/scratch.d/20151012-stack33095084$ python email.py 
Error: unable to send email
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "email.py", line 1, in <module>
    import smtplib
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 46, in <module>
    import email.utils
ImportError: No module named utils
akg@limbo:~/scratch.d/20151012-stack33095084$ mv email.py anything_but_email.py
akg@limbo:~/scratch.d/20151012-stack33095084$ python anything_but_email.py 
Error: unable to send email
```